# How to build an public/private API for some website without involve their developers for an Android client app

Tags: php, android, laravel

There's a way to know if some website has some public or private API  to consume their services without asking their developers? My question here involves about security and developing an API for an website built with any framework or hardcoded. In this case my doubt is because I'm developing some Android client app and I would like to access the same things that appears on website but in Android without using WebView like Netflix do. There's a tool that can be used in this case? Thanks

Comment: In short, no...

Comment: @roelofs You helped me a lot.

Comment: @tessadri Correct me If I'm wrong...There is a site xyz.com they don't have API's for their site what you want is to create API's to interact with their site without their knowledge or without involving them?

Comment: @Vishal my doubt was about to develop an API to interact with their website XYZ.com without involving them. But as far as others answered me there's no way of doing that because it needs to connect to their DB and I don't have access. Unless to dump of all the links of their website or dump their db, am I right?

Comment: Hmmm then in this case it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that any exist. Feel free and don't be afraid of creating your API. No one should be able to find it and use up your resources. You just have to configure your .htaccess and your API so unauthorized users won't be able to use your API and so search engines won't be able to find it.

Comment: I'm grateful for your comment. But there's a way to build an API to some website without knowing their database? Thanks for the knowledge! Portuguese native here.

Comment: No, you can never connect to other people's databases.

Comment: I modified my question to be more specific but it keeps the same way saying this "put on hold as clear what you're asking". I don't know what to do because it keeps this way I'll be blocked of ask another question. Any help here!!